# Finding out the number of ways a bakery can give pies to the homeless?

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> At the end of the day, a bakery gives everything that
>   is unsold to food banks for the needy. If it has $12$ apple
>   pies left at the end of a given day, in how many different
>   ways can it distribute these pies among six food banks for
>   the needy?
>
> How many different
>   ways can the bakery distribute the $12$ apple pies
>   if each of the six food banks is to receive at least
>   one pie?

In order to solve this problem we use the formula

$$\binom{n+x-1}{x-1} $$

Does anyone know where this formula is derived from?

$ n= 12$ and $x =6$

$\Rightarrow \binom{12+6-1}{6-1} = \binom{17}{5}= \binom{17!}{5!*12!} = 6188$

The second part of the problem is where I get stuck at, any tips on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew Conroy has given you a link. When you read it, you will find that the second part can be solved using Theorem $1$ therein.

However, I shall explain a way of solving it that requires you to remember only *one* formula, the one given.

Firstly, give  one pie to each of the food banks. Now you need to distribute only $6$ in any which way, thus $\binom{6+6-1}{6-1}$

Comment: So is the first part correct then?

Comment: So the answer to the second part is $\binom{6+6-1}{6-1} = \binom{11!}{5!*6!} = 462$

Comment: Yep, both parts are correct !